# pytorch error : " Expected isFloatingType(grad.scalar_type()) || (input_is_complex == grad_is_complex) to be true, but got false "

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, complex-numbers, resnet

I am working on the implementation of the classification problem.
My code works well before inserting the complex noise into the output layer.

The following code does not work with Pytorch error

```
def forward(self, x):
    #Encoder Process
    out = self.feature(x)
    out = self.encoder(out)
    out = self.last(out)

    #### Start of error point ######
    batch_size, y = out.size()
    out_real = x[:, 0:int(y / 2)]
    out_comp = x[:, int(y / 2) : y + 1]
    out_comp = out_comp * 1j
    symbols = out_real + out_comp

    n = torch.randn(symbols.shape. dtype=torch.cfloat).to(device) 
    out = symbols + n 
    out_real = out.real 
    out_imag = out.imag 
    out = torch.cat((out_real, out_imag),1)
    #### End of error point ######

    #Decoder process
    out0 = self.decoder0(out)

    out1 = self.decoder1(out0)
    out1 += self.shortcut(out0)

    out2 = self.decoder2(out1)
    out2 += self.shortcut(out1)
```

Before adding `### start of error point ### ... ### end of error point ###` lines the code works well and classification works.
But I get the following error on last line after adding codes:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a131419c404b> in <module>
      6 for epoch in range(start_epoch, start_epoch+total_epoch):
      7     start = time.time()
----> 8     train(epoch, scheduler)
      9     end = time.time()
     10     total_time += (end-start)

<ipython-input-4-d3b479d83256> in train(epoch, scheduler)
     48         top5 = accuracy(outputs, targets, topk=(1, 5))
     49 
---> 50         loss.backward()
     51         optimizer.step()
     52         scheduler.step(epoch +batch_idx/iters)

~\Anaconda3\envs\1DCNN\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    219                 retain_graph=retain_graph,
    220                 create_graph=create_graph)
--> 221         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    222 
    223     def register_hook(self, hook):

~\Anaconda3\envs\1DCNN\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
    130     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    131         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph,
--> 132         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    133 
    134 

RuntimeError: Expected isFloatingType(grad.scalar_type()) || (input_is_complex == grad_is_complex) to be true, but got false.  (Could this error message be improved?  If so, please report an enhancement request to PyTorch.)
```

This forward function models transmitting images on a complex AWGN channel.
So, input `x` is an image. and `### start of error point ### ... ### end of error point ###` parts denotes an adding complex noise.

Is this problem because the complex value is added in the middle of the forward(x) function so the learning does not work?

If input is real, but i want to put the complex value in the middle of the forward function, then what should I do?

Comment: please copy-paste the stack trace of this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error message is the least of your worries.

What are you trying to do? What is the *meaning* of adding complex noise, when you treat your features as two real parts? How is it different than just adding noise to `out`?

If you really want to make your decoder complex, you should leave `out` as a complex tensor and allow the weights of the decoders and shortcuts to be complex as well. This will actually create interactions between the real parts and the imaginary parts of your tensor. Right now, there is no "complex" meaning for the real and imaginary parts of `out`, they are just additional dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added an error message and edited question